# 3D Fourier Matrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab, 3d, fft

I would like to create a Fourier matrix for a 3D fourier transform.
I know that for 1D FFT in Matlab it can be created with dftmtx and I can extend to 2D FFT using kron like this:

```
FT1D=dftmtx(N);
FT2D=kron(FT1D,FT1D);
```

Is there any way to extend it to 3 dimensions? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this problem on my own! I found a suite called On-The-Fly Definition of Custom Matrix Objects in Mathworks:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26611-on-the-fly-definition-of-custom-matrix-objects

Using this suite, the 3D fourier matrix can be defined like follows:

```
Qobj=MatrixObj;
Qobj.Ops.mtimes=@(obj,z) fftn(z);
```

To use it, we can write:

```
y=Qobj*x;
```

It's pretty easy.
I didn't find any other solution to my problem on the internet, so I hope it can be useful for other people too!